# Multiple Linked Lists in Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, linked-list

I am trying to create multiple linked list in java, but at one of the lines i am getting NullPointerException and i am unable to find out the reason as to why such error is arising.

```
import java.util.*;

class node{
int data;
node link;

public node(){
    data = 0;
    link = null;
}
}

public class ll{
    static node add(node head[], int x){
    node temp = new node();
    System.out.println("Enter value");
    temp.data = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
    temp.link = head[x].link;
    head[x].link = temp;
    return head[x];
  }


public static void main(String []args){
    int m =0;
    int x = 0; int flag = 0;
    System.out.println("Enter the size of index");
    m = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
    node []head = new node[m];
    while(x<head.length){
        head[x].data = 0; //error arises here 
        head[x].link = null;
        x++;
    }
    System.out.println(head[0].data); //error arises here.


}
}
```

Comment: `node add` method should not be `static`. You should declare and intialize a new instance of class `ll` to start a new linked list. This `ll` class needs a `node head` field in it. If you want to have multiple linked lists, then create a collection (array, `ll`, `List`, `Set` or whatever) filled with instances of your `ll` class.

Comment: Please follow coding conventions: give classes proper, meaningful names, that start with a capital letter ("ll" isn't one, and it's hard to tell if it's el-el, i-i or 11...), and also indent methods inside their parent class bodies.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because `head[x]`/`head[0]` contains a `null` reference.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a node array but not populated it with anything, so

```
head[x]
```

refers to a null item, and using it to access the .data field results in an NPE.